# How to calculate subtotal in a faster way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Topic': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Value': [3,5,2,9]})
```

But I want to add 'Sub_total' column aggregate by Topic:

```
Topic  Value  Sub_total
A      3      8
A      5      8
B      2      11
B      9      11
```

I have to use groupby and join back with the orignal df. Is there any faster way? Thanks in advance!

```
df.groupby('Topic')['Value'].sum().merge(df, on='Topic')
```

Comment: use transform `df['Sub_total']=df.groupby('Topic')['Value'].transform('sum')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['Sub_total'] = df.groupby('Topic').transform('sum')
```